# Is there a way to reuse Plugins selection in Eclipse Run Configuration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm creating an Eclipse RCP App.

In order to test/debug, I run this App. from within Eclipse IDE using a run configuration.

I would like to be able to reuse this conf., specially the needed plugins list in order to import it in newer Eclipse IDE release or among several Eclipse IDE instance installed on several computers.

Is there a way to export/import this whole config. or at least selected plugins list ?

thks in advance

Comment: If you use a feature based RCP you can just copy the feature.xml which lists all the plug-ins

Comment: Yes I'm using features based product conf. and you're wright, clicking "Launch an Eclipse App." creates the new Run Conf. with necessary plugins.

Comment: The Run Configuration can also be feature based - on the Plug-Ins tab "Launch with" select "features listed below" and list the required features instead of required plug-ins. Launch configuration can be exported and imported.

Comment: Ok,  thks.... but I don't know why this plugins list is not exactly the same as the one computed during export using Maven/Thyco ! 193 plugins used with first method and 199 with Maven/Tycho ! And in both case, plugin validation is OK...

Comment: this is the added plugins by Maven/Thyco : org.apache.commons.codec,
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient,
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore,
org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45,
org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.ssl,
org.eclipse.ecf.ssl

Comment: In the preferences _Plug-in Development > Target Platform_, did you set the target platform that you use in your Tycho build?

Comment: Nope, I've not created a specific target platform. I'm using a repository entry in the parent pom which points to a p2 URL. It works fine and one can easily change this URL. But it is not used for test/debug under Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Sure, that is why the documentation recommends not to do so. The run configuration is specific to a target platform. Has that answered your question?

Comment: Yes, thks greg-449 and howlger.